# How to fix subscribeWith Type parameter error on Rxjava(Kotlin)?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java2

I use Rxjava on Kotlin
and I use `DisposableSingleObserver`, occur error

`Type Parameter bound for E in fun<E: SingleObserver<in ResponseMessage!>!> subscribeWith (observer: E!): E! is not satisfied: inferred type ! is not a subtype of SingleObserver<in ResponseMessage!>!>`

and My Code

```
      val disposable = mFriendRepository.getFriendList()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribeWith(object: DisposableSingleObserver<BaseResponse>() {
                    override fun onSuccess(response: BaseResponse) {
                        Log.d("TEST", "onSuccess getFriendList")
                    }

                    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
                        Log.d("TEST", "onError getFriendList")
                    }
            })
        mCompositeDisposable.add(disposable)
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have to change the type of `DisposableSingleObserver` from `BaseResponse` to `ResponseMessage`